# .NET Core Kestrel Endpoints in Azure App Services

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, kestrel

I'm trying to deploy a .net core web api application to Azure Web services, but i'm getting an error when it try's to start up.

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

for local development, i only run https endpoints.

```
"Kestrel": {
   "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
    }
  }
},
```

I created a private certificate and binded it to my application via Azure. My disconnect is i'm assuming the kestrel instance also needs certificates to run https inside the app service container (linux btw).

Does Microsoft expect you to run the webserver inside the container via HTTP only? and then they proxy the HTTPS traffic to the container? What is the correct way to do this?

am i supposed to generate private certs inside the container with 'dotnet dev-certs https'?

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

> SSL requests never get to your Web App. That's good news for you because it means that you don't need to (and should not) implement any support for SSL into your app
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#NoSSL

Comment: thanks for finding that nugget of documentation. I can't believe it's buried in a "Things you should know blog" from 2017. I feel like they should publicize that more as it's counter to standard security practices.....